# Get the square root of a+bi,when a>0,b>0 in radical form

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex, trigonometry

My code returns this result involves trigonometric functions,

```
ComplexExpand[Sqrt[a + b I], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]
Assuming[{a > 0, b > 0}, FullSimplify@ReIm@Refine@%]
```

[image]

In fact, it can be rewrie by radical form, following is the equivalently result from Maple
[image]

How can I get the radical form result with Mathematica?

Comment: `Assuming[{a > 0, b > 0}, 
 FullSimplify[Through@{Re, Im}@Refine@%, 
  ComplexityFunction -> (100 Count[#, _ArcTan, {0, Infinity}] + 
      LeafCount[#] &)]]`?

Answer (score 1):

Not what you expect, but as a possibility, if nothing else pops up:

```
eq1 = Sqrt[a + b I] == x + I*y;
eq2 = Map[#^2 &, eq1] // Expand;
eq3 = eq2 /. Complex[0, n_] -> 0
eq4 = Equal @@ MapThread[Subtract, {List @@ eq2, List @@ eq3}] // 
  Simplify

(*   a == x^2 - y^2

b == 2 x y    *)
```

Then

```
Solve[{eq3, eq4}, {x, y}] // Simplify

(*  {{x -> -(Sqrt[a - Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]]/Sqrt[2]), 
  y -> (Sqrt[a - Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]] (a + Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]))/(
   Sqrt[2] b)},...   *)
```

Have fun!